# Error installing Pentaho Data Integration (PDI, Kettle) on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

When I try to run PDI on Mac OS Catalina I get this error:

```
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
```

I have tried to update `Info.plist` and `Info.plist~` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http). I also took the application out of mac quarentine as suggested [here](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/167476-Unable-to-launch-Data-Integration-app-on-Mac-OS-X-but-spoon-sh-launches-fine/) and I'm allowing applications from anywhere to run (System Preferences > Security & Privacy)

I also tried different versions of PDI (8, 8.1, 8.2, 9) and no success.

Comment: did you find the issue Airton Gessner?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on macOs Big sur and for me the solution was to downgrade Java to jdk8u202 version.

What I've done:

1. Uninstall java : https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.html
2. Install **jdk-8u202-macosx-x64.dmg** here : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#jre-8u160-oth-JPR